# jar file: main class not found - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, manifest

I have developed a Java project in the IntelliJ IDEA. When I build the jar artifact like described [HERE](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/), everything goes as it is supposed to. But when I double click the generated jar file in the output folder, I get the message:

> Could not find the main class: DoxCalculator.DoxCalculator. Program
>   will exit.

(My project and main class are both called `DoxCalculator`). When I open the `jar` file with `WINRAR`, I notice that only my library files are in there, but no compilation output. Strange, because according to the project structure window at the `artifacts` item, It should be included.

My `MANIFEST.MF` looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: DoxCalculator.DoxCalculator
```

I have searched a lot of questions on the forum, but there seem to be no similar problems asked.

Comment: Can you provide a sample IDEA project to reproduce this problem?

Comment: You are saying that your project name and main class name are both called `DoxCalculator` what exactly do you mean? An IntelliJ IDEA project has nothing to do with the package name. So `DoxCalculator.DoxCalculator` suggests that your package name is `DoxCalculator` and that the class name is `DoxCalculator`. Is that really correct?